# Using #N/A with Bulk API 2.0 to insert null isn't working

Tags: bulk-api-v2

According to SF documentation,  by using #N/A you can insert a null value when using a bulk api. I have a csv that gets loaded into salesforce using bulk api 2.0. When a particular picklist value is blank, I substitute the value #N/A in the column. After the update completes, in Salesforce I see the literal value #N/A for the field's value instead of the picklist being blank. Any thoughts why?

Answer (score 1):

Came back to update this. Was using a in house spark application that transforms large data. In the workflow there was a SQL query which had a REPLACE method to switch any null values to "#N/A". Though it showed as "#N/A" when I looked at the csv file, it appears some sort of hidden characters were being added. When I put "#N/A" in the csv without doing it via the SQL statement it worked.